# Where do you find logs about connections on debian?

Tags: debian, logging, connection

I installed nginx on debian and then tested it with wget localhost and wget 192.168.1.11 to see if it responds to simple requests. After this i changed the default root folder to /var/www and tried testing again.
Now if i try wget locahost it works, but wget 192.168.1.11 gets "connection refussed".
I'm thinking it's a permissions problem, but I can't find a long anywhere that would tell me anything about this. I tried searching through all the files inside /var/log and /var/log/nginx but there is nothing there.
Is there another place where the system logs failed connection attempts? And if not, does anyone know a way I could find the reason for this problem?

```
wget 192.168.1.11 
--2012-08-16 05:59:38-- http://192.168.1.11/  
Connecting to 192.168.1.11:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

**nginx configuration:**

```
server {  
   listen 127.0.0.1:80;  
   server_name testing;  
   root /var/www;  
   index index.php index.html index.htm;  

   location / {

   }  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your configuration?  And maybe `netstat -ln` for good measure?

Comment: 1. Show use exactly output you get when running `wget 192.168.1.11`? 2. As @ShaneMadden said, post your Nginx configuration?

Comment: @ShaneMadden the nginx configuration? and I will add the netstat output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listen 127.0.0.1:80;
```

Means that Nginx is only listening on 127.0.0.1. Look at the output of  `netstat --inet -nlp | grep :80`, you will see something like this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11789/nginx.conf
```

To make the server accessible via the LAN address (192.168.1.11), add a [`listen`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen) directive:

```
listen 127.0.0.1:80;
listen 192.168.1.11:80;
```

then restart Nginx and try again.